# What is the most efficient way to query multiple values via HERE API REST query?

Tags: rest, get, geocoding, here-api, here-maps-rest

### Question:

How do I efficiently handle multiple location requests to the HERE API?

I am new to GET requests and REST generally, but I have a need to get location data, and I'm experimenting with the HERE API. I'm doing this in R, but that fact is irrelevant to my question.

### This works:

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

HERE_API_KEY <- #REMOVED#
url <- "https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/"
zip <- 18615
country <- "United+States"

theRequest <- paste0(url,"geocode?qq=postalCode=",zip,";country=",country,"&apiKey=",HERE_API_KEY)

theResponse <- GET(theRequest)
```

I get a Status 200 message and the data content -- no issues there.

### What I want:

The above example is just one location, but I have a list of several thousand locations I need to look up, eventually trying to determine routing distance between two points in the location data set.

I can create a loop and submit a request for each location one at a time as demonstrated above, but since I have a bunch, I wonder if there is a preferred method to submit the list of locations in one single call (or break it up in groups?) that would be nicer to the the HERE API and efficiently get the data.  Stabbing in the dark, I tried this test for 3 locations:

```
theRequest <- "https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?qq=postalCode=18615;country=United+States&qq=postalCode=L4T1G3;country=Canada&qq=postalCode=62521;country=United+States&apiKey=#REMOVED#"
```

But it didn't work.  Maybe this is not possible and I just don't understand REST, but I want to handle multiple requests as efficiently as possible -- both for myself and for the HERE API service.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the [HERE Geocoding and Search API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/index.html), looping through your data to send individual GET requests for each address is a perfectly valid approach, just make sure that you don't exceed the maximum allowed number of requests per second (RPS) for the plan you have (5 RPS for the Geocoding and Search API in the [Freemium Plan](https://developer.here.com/pricing#plan-details), for example); otherwise your queries will result in error code 429 "Too Many Requests" and you'll have to send them again.

Alternatively, you can use the [HERE Batch Geocoder API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/batch-geocoder/dev_guide/topics/introduction.html), which is designed to process large datasets (up to 1 million records for geocoding or reverse geocoding) with a single API call. Using this service consists of 3 steps:

1. Send a single POST request with all the data you want to geocode or reverse geocode.
2. Call the status endpoint to monitor the status of the job you submitted. You might want to make this type of call periodically until the response indicates that your job is complete and your output is ready to be downloaded.
3. Download your results.

[Here's an example](https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/rest/batch_geocoding/batch-geocode-addresses) of how to use this service; notice that this API supports POST requests instead of GET.

Comment: This appears to be exactly what I was looking for after I was erroneously searching for "multi" and "multi value" instead of "batch."  I will try this out later today, but I intend that this will be the accepted answer.  Thank you.

Comment: Marking this as the accepted answer because it got me where I needed to go.  I worked out an example which I am posting myself nearby showing the exact code I used in R to make it work.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

## Answer with Example

**astro.comma's** answer pointed out where I needed to go to get the HERE API for batches -- and that strictly speaking is the answer and why it is marked as such.  For those that pass by here later, this is my testing script that I used to figure out how to implement the request in R, based on the help I got from astro.comma.

### Sample Data:

***Console:***

```
df_locations[1:5,]  # Show a sample of the data in the data frame

># A tibble: 5 x 3
>  recID country postalCode
>  <int> <fct>   <chr>     
>1     1 CAN     L4T1G3    
>2     2 USA     62521     
>3     3 CAN     H9P1K2    
>4     4 CAN     L6S4K6    
>5     5 USA     52632     

dput(df_locations[1:5,])  # For ease of reproducibility, here's dput():


structure(list(recID = 1:5, country = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L), .Label = c("CAN", "USA", "MEX"), class = "factor"), 
    postalCode = c("L4T1G3", "62521", "H9P1K2", "L6S4K6", "52632"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

***Script:***

```
library(httr)
library(tidyverse)
    
HERE_API_KEY <- "YOU-CANT-HAVE-THIS-BECAUSE-ITS-MINE"

url <- "https://batch.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/jobs"

# Write df_locations to pipe-delimited text file to prep for POST
write.table(
  df_locations,
  file = "locations.txt",
  quote = FALSE,
  sep = "|",
  row.names = FALSE
  )
    
# Assemble the POST request url to start the job
theRequest <-
  paste0(
        url,
        "?&apiKey=",
        HERE_API_KEY,
        "&action=run&header=true",
        "&indelim=%7C&outdelim=%7C",
        "&outcols=recId%2CseqNumber%2CseqLength%2CdisplayLatitude",
        "%2CdisplayLongitude%2Ccity%2CpostalCode%2Ccountry",
        "&outputCombined=true"
  )

# Now submit the POST request along with the location file
theResponse <-
    POST(url = theRequest, body = upload_file("locations.txt"))
```

***Console:***

```
>theResponse
Response [https://batch.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/jobs?&apiKey=YOU-CANT-HAVE-THIS-BECAUSE-ITS-MINE&action=run&header=true&indelim=%7C&outdelim=%7C&outcols=recId%2CseqNumber%2CseqLength%2CdisplayLatitude%2CdisplayLongitude%2Ccity%2CpostalCode%2Ccountry&outputCombined=true]
Date: 2021-12-27 00:45
Status: 200
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Size: 209 B
```

***Script:***

```
# Extract the Request ID so we can check for completion status of the job, and 
# use it to identify / download the zip file when complete.

reqID <- content(theResponse)$Response$MetaInfo$RequestId
```

***Console:***

```
>reqID
[1] "XS9wSVt3y0Dch1Q48gX1xohewUKIw595"  # or looks like this -- I changed it here.
```

***Script:***

```
# After letting some time pass (about a minute for my test file), I check
# status of the job with a GET request:

JOB_status <-
    GET(paste0(url, "/", reqID, "?action=status&apiKey=", HERE_API_KEY))
```

***Console:***

```
>content(JOB_status)
$Response
$Response$MetaInfo
$Response$MetaInfo$RequestId
[1] "XS9wSVt3y0Dch1Q48gX1xohewUKIw595"


$Response$Status
[1] "completed"         #  There are other statuses (statii?), but this one we care about.

$Response$JobStarted
[1] "2021-12-27T00:46:36.000+0000"

$Response$JobFinished
[1] "2021-12-27T00:46:49.000+0000"

$Response$TotalCount
[1] 2080                # Ignore this -- I only provided you with first 5 rows

$Response$ValidCount
[1] 2080

$Response$InvalidCount
[1] 0

$Response$ProcessedCount
[1] 2080

$Response$PendingCount
[1] 0

$Response$SuccessCount
[1] 2076

$Response$ErrorCount
[1] 4
```

***Script:***

```
# I stayed with GET request via httr, but no reason you can't switch to some other
# method for download like cURL

 COMPLETED_JOB <-
    GET(paste0(url, "/", reqID, "/result?apiKey=", HERE_API_KEY))
    
job_content <- content(x = COMPLETED_JOB, as = "raw")  # This extract hexidecimal data which is the zipped content -- has to get extracted to be useful.

writeBin(job_content, con = "Processed_locations.zip")  # Writes the binary data to file.

unzip(zipfile = "Processed_locations.zip")  # Extracts the zip file as its own text file.
```

#### End result file:

```
recId|SeqNumber|seqLength|recId|seqNumber|seqLength|displayLatitude|displayLongitude|city|postalCode|country
1|1|1|1|1|1|43.70924|-79.658|Mississauga|L4T 1G3|CAN
2|1|1|2|1|1|39.83972|-88.92881|Decatur|62521|USA
3|1|1|3|1|1|45.47659|-73.78061|Dorval|H9P 1K2|CAN
4|1|1|4|1|1|43.75666|-79.71021|Brampton|L6S 4K6|CAN
5|1|1|5|1|1|40.4013|-91.3848|Keokuk|52632|USA
```